# How do I hide my work Google Plus profile?

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

I use G+ with my personal Gmail account, it is good and people can find and circle me. Lately I've got a job in an IT company where they use Google Apps and they share miscellaneous things internally via G+, which is all good as well.

But the problem is that I now have two G+ profiles under the same name, and when I go home G+ ask me if I want to circle my work G+ account, and vice versa.

I also don't want half of the people to circle my work profile and the other half circle my personal, I just want everyone to add me on my personal one.

Is there a way to hide my work G+ profile so it doesn't get fragmented?

Answer (score 2):

When logged in to your work account go to https://plus.google.com/settings and uncheck the box next to "Help others discover my profile in search results."

Comment: I think this will work in most cases, but bear in mind that Google will suggest connections based on your contacts/who you email as well. If any of your personal contacts have your work email address, they may still be prompted to connect to your profile.

Comment: I love Google Apps but this drives me crazy; I hate that integration between multiple accounts is so poor or non-existent. I don't want to have to manage multiple connections or have people adding my work account to theirs, I just want one Google+ account for people to see/use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest asking your work's Google+ administrator:  they must have come across this problem before.    And they must have some policies re linking your personal profile to work - the problems may arise when you leave the company.